# Template specialisation for any pointer type

Tags: c++, templates

I've got the following class

```
class MyClass {
    std::string id;
    int count;

    MyClass (const std::string& id, const int count) :
        id(id), count(count)
    {}
public:
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    MyClass (const T& t, Args&&... args) : 
        MyClass(t->getId(), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}
};
```

In my real case it's more complex and has more than one private constructor implementations, so template actually makes sence.

I also have few classes with `getId` method like this:

```
class HasId {
    std::string id;

public:
    HasId (const std::string& id) :
        id(id)
    {}

    const std::string& getId () {
        return id;
    }
};
```

So in my code i can do this:

```
auto a = std::make_shared<HasId>("foobar");
MyClass b(a, 42);
HasId c("foobaz");
MyClass d(&c, 265);
```

But I've got a problem when `Args...` are implicitly convertible to the expected constructor args, but has different type. Like this:

```
auto a = std::make_shared<HasId>("foobar");
MyClass b(a, 42.0);
```

In this case compiler tries to substitute `string` and `double` into templated ctor and obviously fails. I know I can modify private ctors and initialize `id` field inside templated ctor, but I wonder if it's possible to specify single template for pointer types only (`std::shared_ptr<T>`, `T*`, etc.).

Comment: Accepting smart pointer by reference is typically not a good idea. Also I don't see why failure to compile `MyClass b(a, 42.0);` is wrong. second function parameter does not match that private constructor.

Comment: @VTT Ownership of the data inside the smart pointer is not transferred or shared, so passing a reference is okay IMO.

Comment: Herb sutter's [GotW91](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-91-smart-pointer-parameters/) again...

Comment: @VTT you're right, parameter does not match the private ctor, but without teplated ctor compiler will just call implicit conversion here, so the question is how to force such implicit conversion with templated ctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the template constructor to only participate in overload resolution if `t->getId()` is valid. That can be done by adding a (dummy) template parameter

```
template<typename T, typename = decltype(std::declval<T&>()->getId()), typename... Args>
MyClass (const T& t, Args&&... args) : 
    MyClass(t->getId(), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
{}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/493ee627caafbf51)

However in your case, it would be much easier to just

```
template<typename T>
MyClass (const T& t, int count) : 
    MyClass(t->getId(), count)
{}
```